# compositeDisposable.dispose() causes NPE

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Calling .dispose() during request causes NPE. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Error message

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: The callable returned a null value
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:44)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3575)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
        at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Well there is a `fromCallable` that breaks for some reason in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not from calling `dispose`, this is the result of `fromCallable` that is `null`. In Rxjava 2 you cannot progate nulls through the steam. It'll cause a null pointer exception like you are experiencing. You need to check your code and figure out a way to avoid returning null. Maybe using an empty object to denote the absence of value.

There is an exception to this and perhaps the best solution to this problem. `Maybe.fromCallable` will return an empty observable if the method returns `null`. This might be the most accurate thing to do in your case.